# Flutter Png Image Pixelated when in an Icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I cant figure out why my image is pixelated in my flutter app.
The image is of good size and quality but on the app it appears
pixelated .

The image:
[image: The image]

The App:

[image: The App]

The code:

```
Image.asset(
            "assets/trolley.png",
             width: 40,
            height: 40,

          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use font svg icons in this case
try this https://fluttericon.com 
[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZYqmM3daO0) about it

Comment: thanks ,following the guide to create my own custom icon worked. converted Png to Svg then to Icon